# ASP.NET MVC Session Expiring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, timeout

I have a requirement to ensure the session expires only after 8 hours.  However, users continually say they are getting kicked out multiple times throughout the day

Here are the settings I have:

1. web.config:

   forms name=".MYUNIQUFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="/Login"   enableCrossAppRedirects="true" requireSSL="false" timeout="480"
2. IIS 7 - application pool - Idle Timeout set to 480
3. ASP --> Session Properties --> 8:00:00

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the apppool is not being recycled or iis restarted?

Comment: This is deployed on a client server but I know IIS would not be getting restarted in business hours.  Would the apppool recycle be a manual process?  I doubt they would be recycling.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting incorrect attribute in your web.config.

Instead of setting:

```
<forms timeout="480" ... />
```

> [Specifies the time, in integer minutes, after which the cookie
>   expires.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.85).aspx)

you should set:

```
<sessionState timeout="480" ... />
```

> [Specifies the number of minutes a session can be idle before it is
>   abandoned.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx)